# On submitting the Form how to read file upload control data in view coming from ajax

Tags: django, django-views

When I submit the form I don't want page to be reload that's why I use ajax and get data on form submission to ajax and ajax will send request to corresponding view . but I am unable to find code for file upload control in view. I am unable to get data from:

```
myfile = request.FILES['myfile'] 
myfile =request.FILES['myfile'].read()
```

but i am always getting error :

> if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['filename'] raise
>   MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
>   django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'filename'

this is my form :

```js
    $(document).ready(function(evt){
       
        $(document).on('submit','#myform',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        var thisForm=$(this).serialize();
        var action=$(this).attr('action');
        var method=$(this).attr('method');
      var formData = new FormData($('#myform')[0]);
    console.log(formData);  
    
       $.ajax({
            url: action,
            type: method,
            data: formData,
             success: function (data) {
                 alert(data)
             },
            cache: false,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false
        });
        });
    
    });
```

```html
<form action="{% url 'process_file' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
                    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 firstblock padMin">
                        <h3>Input Data</h3>
                        <ul>
<li><input type="file" name="files[]"  required accept=".csv" id="file_data" ></li>
                            <li class="checkboxIn">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="id" id="id" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                               
                                <input type="number" name="train_fraction" id="train_fraction" required value={% if post_data %} {{fiction}}  {% else %} 0.7 {% endif %} min="0.1" step="0.1" >
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg custom-process" type="submit">Process</button>
    and there are other control also 
    </form>
```

Here is my view function in Python:

```
@csrf_exempt
def process_file(request):
    #From submit action
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['filename']:
        print (request.POST)
        id = '0' if request.POST.get('id',False)==False else '1'
        res = '1' if 'res' in request.POST and request.POST['res']=='on' else '0'
        ae_res = '1' if 'ae_res' in request.POST and request.POST['ae_res'] == 'on' else '0'
        event_handling = '1' if 'event_handling' in request.POST and request.POST['event_handling'] == 'on' else '0'
        threshold = request.POST['threshold'] if 'threshold' in request.POST else '1.0'
        samplerate = request.POST['samplerate'] if 'samplerate' in request.POST else '0.1'



       # myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
      #  myfile =request.FILES['myfile'].read()


    #default action
    return render(request, 'process_file.html',{})
```

how to read file control data in view and I am always getting an error saying 500 error whenever I open a console in the browser

Answer (score 0):

`request.FILES['filename']` should be `request.FILES.getlist('files[]')`

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist

Comment: Sir I am sending entire form in ajax and want to read entire form data in django . i  am stuck at this place .